# D3 - Some Tick Marks and Grid Lines Don't Render

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have D3 application creating a plot that requires tick marks and grid lines. Periodically some of the tick marks and grid lines disappear. Also some of the grid lines are thicker. Note that I require both left/right y-axis tick marks and top/bottom x-axis tick marks.

### Grid Different Stroke Widths

[image: Different stroke widths]

### Lost Tick Marks and Grid Lines

[image: Lost Tick marks and Grid Lines]

Below is the basic grid

```js
    //================grid lines=============
    var height = PlotHeight-30
    //---Draw the x Grid lines, dynamic: changes vs Julian/Calendar select---
    GridXG = GridG.append("g")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("shape-rendering" ,"crispEdges")
    .attr("id", "gridXG")
    .attr("class", "gridX")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "lightgrey")
    .attr("stroke-opacity", ".7")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height) + ")")

    if(DateFormat=="Julian")
    GridXG.call(make_x_axisJulian() //---default--
        .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat("")
    )
    else if(DateFormat=="Calendar")
        GridXG.call(make_x_axisCalendar()
        .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat("")
    )

    // Draw the y Grid lines
    GridYG = GridG.append("g")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("shape-rendering" ,"crispEdges")
    .attr("id", "gridYG")
    .attr("class", "gridY")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "lightgrey")
    .attr("stroke-opacity", ".7")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1.5")
    .call(make_y_axis()
        .tickSize(-XaxisWidth, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat("")
    )
```

Does anyone have a few suggestions that could send me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to zoom on the missing grid lines with you browser to see if it shows up ?

Comment: @TimB - I just tried it. No change.

Comment: They are probably too thin (or clipped to be too thin) so the UA omits drawing them.

Comment: @altocumulus Yes!!, I changed "shape-rendering" from "crispEdges" to "geometricPrecision" That did the trick..thanks

Comment: @RobertLongson According to the last comment by Francis Hemsher my assumption, that this was a duplicate, was correct. The solution to that other question was successfully applied to this problem. Could you please dupe-hammer this post?